# why does repete @section content in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

working with Laravel and I have following welcome page

```
</head>
<body>
</div><!--container-->
        @include('partials._footer')
        @endsection

        @else

        @section('fixx')
        <p>Rivers</p>
        @endsection
        @endguest
    </body>
</html>
```

and app.blade.php

```
 @guest
        <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
        </main>
        @else
        <main class="py-4">
        @include('partials._nav')
        
            @yield('fixx')
            
            @include('partials._footer')   
        </main>
        @endguest
```

_nav.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/nav.css') }}" />

<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
<!-- Page Content -->
    @yield('one')
    @if('Auth')
    @yield('two')
    @endif
</div>
```

but when I see welcome page with logged user I could see `@yield('one')` contents in the `@yield('two')`

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: I think your `@if('Auth')` condition is wrong. Can you try with `@auth` instead?

Comment: error generates here

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show `@yield('two')` for logged in users, try this:

```
@auth
    @yield('two')
@endauth
```

BTW, there are a few blade directives missing in your markup. Make sure you have a matching start and end tags for each directive you are using.

https://laravel.com/docs/blade#blade-directives

**Edit:**

If you want to hide `@yield('one')` for logged-in users:

```
// usign @guest
@guest
  @yield('one')
@else
  @yield('two')
@endauth
```

Comment: `yield` should be `@yield`

Comment: I did it but it is showing as @yield('one') also

Comment: Do you want to hide `@yield('one')` for logged-in users?